# Minimum over measure

Tags: measure-theory

suppose I have a set defined by:
\begin{align}
A= \{ (x,y): \inf_z f(x,y,z) \le d \}
\end{align}

Now, if I define set:
\begin{align}
a(z)= \{ (x,y):  f(x,y,z) \le d \}
\end{align}

Is it correct to say that measure of A
is:
\begin{align}
\mu(A)=\inf_z \mu(a(z))
\end{align}
Thank you

Comment: you mean $\inf_a \mu(a)$, right?

Comment: I made some edits. Basically, I am trying to say that the measure of A is the smallest of all set a's

Comment: since $a(z) \subset A$, we have $\mu(a(z)) \leq \mu(A)$, so maybe you want to say $\sup$ instead of $\inf$?

Comment: So, is $\mu(A)=\sup_z\mu(a(z))$, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative:

Take $f(x,y,z) = |x-z| +|y|$, then $\inf_z f(x,y,z) = |y|$, so $A = \{|y| \leq d\}$, $\mu(A) =\infty$.

But $a(z) \subset [z-d,z+d] \times[-d,d]$, so $\mu(a(z)) < 4d^2, \forall z$.

Comment: So, how would you write $A$ in terms of $a(z)$.

Comment: $A = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_z a(z, d+\frac{1}{n})$, with the obvious modification of notation

Comment: If you replace all $\leq$ by $<$, then simply $A=\cup_z a(z)$

Comment: You are welcome